# Can't connect to onion sites

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, onion-services, torcheck

Installed the Tor browser bundle on my Ubuntu 14.10 box a while back and am now trying to learn about onion sites. My Tor browser passes the check.torproject.org test, but can not connect to idnxcnkne4qt76tg.onion (which I understand is Tor's onion connectivity test site)... it tries for a while and then throws the error : The connection has timed out

Can someone help me correct this?

Comment: I cannot connect to this site either, so it might be down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tor's sysadmin team has disabled the support for this hidden service. See [trac #11567](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/11567) for some information. When you want to test some hidden services you can choose one from:

- [fine example](http://duskgytldkxiuqc6.onion/)
- [DuckDuckGo search engine](http://3g2upl4pq6kufc4m.onion/)
- [Facebooks's onion service](https://facebookcorewwwi.onion/)
- test one or more hidden services from the [list of onion domains](https://ahmia.fi/address/)