# I can't access any Tor links

Tags: onion-services

Everytime I try to access any Tor website with .onion, this message appears

> Unable to connect
>
> Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at aaaaaaaaaa.onion.

The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.

If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network connection.
If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Tor Browser is permitted to access the Web.
I'm using Tor as browser.

And when I go to this:

https://check.torproject.org/

It says it is configured to use Tor

Comment: The sites are probably down. Also see these threads: http://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/4451/cant-connect-to-onion-sites, http://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/4617/cant-connect-to-onion-sites-hidden-service-is-unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

Well the Browser already told you what possible happened.

1. The site is too busy

   > Most tor-websites are not connected with a high bandwidth - so this can be possible on a hyped website or on a frequently accessed one.
2. Site could be temporarily unavailable

   > Most of the Tor-Sites are not 100% up - they are often only 20% of the time online.

If other (non .onion) Sites work - Tor-Network is fully functional and the .onion site you connect to is offline.